# Server with Froxlor UI; Permission error with PHP FPM and nginx

Tags: nginx, permissions, php-fpm

I'm running a vhost that provides a Froxlor web UI for configuration. Froxlor generates the config files for everything in its scope automatically.

The problem I'm currently facing is that Froxlor creates a config file for PHP FPM that generates the socket for the corresponding domain user, lets call him `dom-user:dom-user` while the nginx server is configured to be run as user `www-data:www-data` which is correct.

That however unfortunately seems to lead to the problem that I get permission denied errors when PHP tries to access the socket because it's not owned by `www-data:www-data`.

I can of course change the user for the socket manually in the config files, but I would have to do that every time after Froxlor regenerated the config files. There must be a configuration flaw somewhere in Froxlor that I haven't been able to find.

Maybe that's something someone around here has already encountered too and knows how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding `dom-user` and `www-data` to each other's groups.